# Recursion for implementing a lattice path counting

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, path, grid

I am trying to solve the problem of finding the number of paths in a lattice (some grid) using recursion.

I wrote the following code which suppose to find total number of valid paths in a lattice/grid. In a valid path (to the bottom right corner of the grid), you can only move in one of two directions: right or down.

I'm not sure it is correct way of using recursion. 
**Is there any better way of solving this problem / using recursion to solve it?**

Thanks

```js
var array = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]];
var lastRowIndex=2;
var lastColIndex=3;
var count=0;
function pathCount(i,j){
    if(!(array[i-1]==undefined) || !(array[i][j-1]==undefined)){
        if(!(array[i-1]==undefined)){
            --i;
            pathCount(i,j);
            i++;
        }
        if(!(array[i][j-1]==undefined)){
            --j;
            pathCount(i,j); 
        }
    }else{
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
console.log(pathCount(lastRowIndex,lastColIndex));
```

Comment: This *is* using recursion? And what is a path on a grid?!

Comment: `lastRowIndex * lastColIndex` might be slightly easier.

Comment: how?? coudn't understand.

Comment: @Jonas W. the multiplication you mentioned is not right.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is fine. basically it does what it should.**

Assuming a valid path is constructed only by moving down the grid or moving to the right,
notice you don't actually need the array, just a size parameter and a pointer to the current position traveled by your algorithm.

As any regression problem let us start by something simple, an induction basis.

First notice, in a linear grid (size 1xN or Nx1) there is only one valid path.
Now, if you are at the (i,j) square, you only have 2 possibilities of moving, hence
the total number of paths is a sum of two element:

1. The number of valid paths from square (i-1,j)
2. The number of valid paths from square (i,j-1)

(notice a validity check on these argument is needed, since they are bounded by the possible indices of the grid).

so a possible recursion is:

```js
let size = 10;
let grid = {
  width: size,
  height: size
};
let currentPosition = {
  x: size,
  y: size
};

function validDecrement(value) {
  return (value - 1 >= 1 ? value - 1 : 1);
}

function countValidPaths(gridObject, startingLocation) {
  if (startingLocation.x === 1 || startingLocation.y === 1) {
    return 1;
  } else if (startingLocation.x > 1 && startingLocation.y > 1) {
    return countValidPaths(gridObject, {
      x: startingLocation.x,
      y: validDecrement(startingLocation.y)
    }) + countValidPaths(gridObject, {
      x: validDecrement(startingLocation.x),
      y: startingLocation.y
    });
  } else {
    console.log(`invalid input: grid: ${gridObject}, startingLocation: ${startingLocation}`);
  };
}

console.log(`Number of valid paths over a ${grid.height} by ${grid.width} grid is : ${countValidPaths(grid,currentPosition)}`);
```

Of course - there is a much better approach to solving this method rather than a recursion. the number you are seeking is simply the binomial coefficient `C((grid.with-1)+(grid.height-1),(grid.width-1))` - [lattice paths counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_path)